# Implementing scheme style macros in clojure

Tags: clojure, scheme

I often read debates about why hygenic macros are better and that clojure's macro system is based upon Common Lisp and is not hygenic.

My question is: can a scheme style macro system be implemented in clojure and what are some examples of scheme style macros implanted in other lisps.

Comment: To the people voting to close this as "too broad", I disagree. It asks not just whether something is possible, but also for examples of the thing being implemented. It is a specific question that is possible to answer specifically (as I tried to do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "Scheme-style macro system", I'm not sure if you mean `syntax-rules` (the simple pattern style system) or `syntax-case` (the more flexible system which, along with `datum->syntax`, actually does let you bend or flat-out break hygiene).

Also, Racket has [`syntax-parse`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html), which a bit simpler to use than `syntax-case` and (among other things) makes it pleasant to write macros which give intelligible error messages.

Regardless of which you mean, there is a [Clojure project that purports to implement aspects of all three](https://github.com/qbg/syntax-rules).  However I haven't tried it and I can't vouch for how successfully it does so.

Comment: Thanks Greg, So if there can be facility for both to exist within a language, then why are people so fixated on one versus the other?

Comment: @zcaudate Given you have an unhygenic `define-macro` you can easily make any other macro system with it. With Schemes `syntax-rules` only standards (R5RS and R7RS-small) you cannot. Hygiene is pretty much an abstraction that reduces bugs and some people want that rather than power. Most implementations have both.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's accurate to say that Clojure's macro system is not hygienic. One similar discussion I have seen refers to common lisp's system for reader macros (which Clojure does not have) as being not hygienic because they lack a mechanism to keep reader macros in different modules from replacing each other. It was an explicit and intentional design decision to build the language such that Scheme-style macros where not included.